How to configure HuggingFaceEndpoint in Langchain
I'm trying to use this model
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEndpoint
repo_id="google/flan-t5-large"
huggingface_llm = HuggingFaceEndpoint(
huggingfacehub_api_token=HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN,
repo_id=repo_id,
temperature=0,
max_new_tokens=200)

from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
def flan_process(tema, pregunta):
template = "Eres un experto asistente en {tema}. Responde a la siguiente pregunta: {pregunta}"
prompt=PromptTemplate(template=template,input_variables=["tema","pregunta"])

flan_chain = prompt | huggingface_llm

respuesta=flan_chain.invoke({"tema":tema, "pregunta":pregunta})

return respuesta

tema=input("Ingrese el tema: ")
pregunta=input("Ingrese la pregunta: ")

flan_reply=flan_process(tema, pregunta)
print(f"Respuesta Flan: {flan_reply}")

But I always get this error The following model_kwargs are not used by the model: ['return_full_text', 'watermark', 'stop_sequences', 'stop'] (note: typos in the generate arguments will also show up in this list)
Any idea please?
Thanks

I encountered the same problem, it seems like it is a bug in the implementation of the HuggingFaceEndpoint class that makes it not work with certain models like the google/flan-t5-large one, which you (and also I) are using. I read this on an issue on GitHub.
Link to issue
I hope this helps you!

HuggingFaceEndpoint used to work with google/flan-t5-large but not any more. In case, you're still looking for a free model to try, here's what I'm using
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEndpoint
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
repo_id = "mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2"
# repo_id = "meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B"
llm = HuggingFaceEndpoint(
    repo_id = repo_id,
    temperature = 0.5,
    huggingfacehub_api_token=HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN,
    max_new_tokens = 250,
)

Mistral-7B and Llama3.2 are quite nice models and free for access through API
